# Don't see Code Signing Entitlements in xcode target properties

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

I am trying to build an adhoc build for my app , I am following the instructions on the apple's documentation which says

> Select the Target and open the Build
>   settings inspector. In the ‘Code
>   Signing Entitlements’ build setting,
>   type in the filename of the new
>   Entitlements.plist file including the
>   extension. There is no need to specify
>   a path unless you have put the
>   Entitlements.plist file somewhere
>   other than the top level of the
>   project.

But i dont see that section , what am i missing ?[image]

Comment: are you trying to build for the app store or for ad hoc development?? Apple gives instructions for code signing several places on their website - However I definitely feel that the most concise and easy to follow directions are in the developer program portal.

Comment: this is for adhoc build. Yeah these are the instructions from their dev website.

Comment: some possibilities: try doing "get info" on the root of the project, rather than the target.  try switching to "device" from "simulator".  Make sure you have all the right certificates in your keychain.  I see you're set to GCC 4.0; I think the new default is GCC 4.2--what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: This happened to me and I also had to resort to creating a new project. Briefly tried to compare the project files, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses . In the end i just gave up and created a new project and copied all my files into it . The new project has that section in there . I am not sure how that project got into that state . Emailed Apple support last week , yet to hear back from them , will update the post once I hear back from there.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure your "Base SDK" property for your Distribution target configuration is set to Device and not to Simulator. I had the same problem, and this worked for me.

Found the answer here:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1896569

Comment: Thanks . But i still dont see that section

Answer (score 3):

you must create the file Entitlements.plist and add it to your resource folder in your build.

once it is added,

you need to double click on the first field in the Code Signing section and type in Entitlements.plist

I don't have my mac in front of me I hope this is enough to get started.  If you are trying to make a distribution of the build you need to have a distribution channel.

**Edit for the Comment**
you need to double click the field to the right of the first field and type the word Entitlements.plist once you close out the window it will appear in the list

Comment: thanks, but as in the screenshot first field in the code signing section is not entitlement

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but in the same window I changed Base SDK from iphone simulator to iphone device and Entitlements appeared.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by opening the PROJECT get info (go to Project -> Edit Project Settings or right click on the project) and in the General tab make sure the "Base SDK for All Configurations" at the bottom is set to Device and not Simulator.

Comment: thanks matt. I had the same problem, and setting the "Base SDK for All Configurations" in the PROJECT Info screen fixed this as you suggested. Great sleuthing... talk about somewhat obscure.

Answer (score 2):

You should need to set the path of the Entitlements.plist file

I have set in the my project see below screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Target Build Settings->Architecture, Make sure your **Base SDK** is set to Device and not Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen in Xcode 4 if you are on the Basic tab in your project settings. To see Code Signing Entitlements you need to have the All tab selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it first, click the gear on the lower left. If that doesn't work, I would go ask Apple. If it's in their documentation they should be more than happy to clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

What version of xcode are you running?  Here's a screenshot of mine that clearly show the Code Signing Entitlements field:

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/814ef82625.png]

Comment: 3.1.3 . I dont see that section at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I've seen strange things happen in the build tab of the target info before, as if it becomes confused between configurations. I took the approach of simplifying the operation to the bare minimum and it seemed to sort itself out. Mind you, this was in the midnight hours after a long shift and it may have been me that was getting confused. I hesitate to mention it but it will only take a few seconds to try and you may be able to put my mind at rest

From the main Xcode window toolbar
Set the Active SDK to the "Device" item that has (project settings) after it
Set the Active Configuration to the one concerned with (here distribution)

In Target -> GetInfo->Build 
Select configuration of "active (distribution)"

Comment: That didnt bring the section back .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue, moving to a new SDK, I've dropeed 2.1 support but it was still the base SDK in the project. By changing the base sdk, my certificates now appears again!